# Wordpress search result postmeta and term

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, join

What´s the problem with this?

I´m trying to search in wp_postmeta and wp_terms but i getting just one or another, never both. I already tried change OR to AND in WHERE, but nothing happens and no result is printed.

Thanks!

```
$join .= "

    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id 
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms ON $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id 

";
```

and this...

```
$where .= " 

    OR ( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%".get_search_query()."%' AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' ) 
    OR ( $wpdb->terms.name LIKE '%".get_search_query()."%' AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' ) 

";
```

---

**UPDATE 1**

---

After reading here https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/mistake-in-documentation-query-posts-by-custom-fields/ — I´ve changed the two "inner join" for "join" and it worked fine. I don´t know exactly why it works. But unfortunately still very slow to get the results.

Could you tell me if this is the best approach for what I'm looking for?

```
add_filter( 'posts_join', 'custom_search_join' );
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'custom_search_where' );
add_filter( 'posts_distinct', 'custom_search_distinct' );


function custom_search_join( $join ) {

global $wpdb;

if( !is_admin() ) {

    if( is_search() ) {

        $join .= "

        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id 
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id 
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON $wpdb->terms.term_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id 

        ";

        print_r( $join ) ;

    }

}

return $join;

}

function custom_search_where( $where ) {

global $wpdb;

if( !is_admin() ) {

    if( is_search() ) {

        $where .= " 

        OR ( $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%".get_search_query()."%' ) 
        OR ( $wpdb->terms.name LIKE '%".get_search_query()."%' ) 
        AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'

        ";

        print_r( $where ) ;

    }

}

return $where;

}

function custom_search_distinct( $where ) {

global $wpdb;

if( !is_admin() ) {

    if( is_search() ) {

        return "DISTINCT";

    }

}

return $where;

}
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

---

After some research and study.

1. Define list of ACF fields that will be searched
2. Define taxonomies to be searched

Running fast so far.
If anyone knows of a way to improve this code I really appreciate it.

```
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'busca_acf', 500, 2 );

function lista_campos_acf() {

    $lista_campos_acf = [ 'acf-field-example' ];
    return $lista_campos_acf;

}

function lista_taxonomias() {

    $lista_taxonomias = [ 'post_tag', 'category', 'example_taxonomy' ];
    return $lista_taxonomias;

}

function busca_acf( $where, $wp_query ) {

if( !is_admin() ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $termos = remove_accents( $wp_query->query_vars[ 's' ] );

    $exploded = array_map( 'strtolower', explode( ' ', $termos ) );

    $lista_campos_acf = lista_campos_acf();

    $lista_taxonomias = lista_taxonomias();

    $where = '';

    foreach( $exploded as $tag ) {

        $where .= " 

            AND (

                ( wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%$tag%' ) 

                OR ( wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%$tag%' ) 

                OR EXISTS (

                    SELECT * 
                    FROM wp_postmeta
                    WHERE post_id = wp_posts.ID
                    AND ( ";

                        foreach( $lista_campos_acf as $campo_acf ) {

                            if( $campo_acf == $lista_campos_acf[0] ) {

                                $where .= " ( meta_key LIKE '%" . $campo_acf . "%' AND meta_value LIKE '%$tag%' ) ";

                            }

                            else {

                                $where .= " OR ( meta_key LIKE '%" . $campo_acf . "%' AND meta_value LIKE '%$tag%' ) ";

                            }

                        }

                    $where .= ")

                )

                OR EXISTS (

                    SELECT * 
                    FROM wp_terms 
                    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id 
                    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id 
                    WHERE ( ";

                        foreach ( $lista_taxonomias as $tax ) {

                            if( $tax == $lista_taxonomias[0] ) {

                                $where .= "taxonomy = '" . $tax . "'";

                            }

                            else {

                                $where .= "OR taxonomy = '" . $tax . "'";

                            }

                        }

                    $where .= ")
                    AND object_id = wp_posts.ID
                    AND wp_terms.name LIKE '%$tag%'

                )

            )

        ";

    }

    return $where;

}

}
```

Comment: You do realize this is the very difficult way to query posts by meta / terms? You should check out [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), especially the [meta query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) and [term query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) sections.  As to _why_, you've only shared _part of your query_, so it's impossible to tell.  Why don't you also share the fully built query.

Comment: I am trying to extend the default Wordpress search. Trying to fetch the word that the user looks for in wp_postmeta and wp_terms.

I'm not sure how I can do this using just one WP_query.

I read about this approach I put up in a post. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: I recently did exactly this, and it was non-trivial - I had to leverage two different hooks, and ended up doing some preg_replace work to get ita ll wired up properly.  (It seems that the "normal" WP Query can only be hacked so far).  Note - if you share what the entire query ends up being when you are done, that would be most useful.  Use `$wpdb->last_query` and share the results here.